# Prove that given a uniformly continuous function $f\colon \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\to \mathbb{R}$ we have that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)$ exists.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

So I have to prove what is in the title. I tried to go from the given definition of uniform continuity (for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ $|x-y|<\delta$ implies that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$) and end up with the definition for a limit (for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that if $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ $0<|x|<\delta$ implies that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$). I tried using the fact that for uniform continuity we can manipulate $|x-y|<\delta$ to $|x|<\delta+|y|$ but I really have no idea if that's the right route or how to go from there, especially since I can't set $y=0$ due to the domain. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: Take a sequence $x_n\to 0$ and show that $f(x_n)$ is a Cauchy-sequence.